# how to fined a process started with nohup after closing terminal?

Tags: linux, process, terminal, nohup

I have to ssh to a server for running some codes that take a long time to finish. so I need to use `nohup` command.

I started multiple processes using the nohup command like this:

```
  nohup julia test.jl > Output1.txt &
  nohup julia test.jl > Output2.txt &
  nohup julia test.jl > Output3.txt &
  nohup julia test.jl > Output4.txt &
```

the problem is that I closed the terminal and when I opened another terminal 
I couldn't get the process name and ID using `jobs -l`.

I tried using `ps -p` but it answers me for all of the above processes with the same answer `julia`.

my question is " how can I specify which process is which?" note that only Output file name is different in these processes.

and

"how can I prevent such a problem in the future?"

Thanks for your time and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to distinguish between these processes are through there `stdout` redirections and there is no good way of doing that using `ps` command.

If you have `pgrep` installed, you can use that with a simple `for loop` to know which `pid` correspond to which output file. Something like the following,

```
for pid in $(pgrep julia); 
do 
   echo -n "$pid: "; 
   readlink -f /proc/${pid}/fd/1; 
done
```

`/proc/${pid}/fd/1` represents the `stdout` for the process with `pid`. It's a symlink, so you need to use `readlink` to check the source.

Output:

```
12345: /path/to/output1.txt
12349: /path/to/output2.txt
12350: /path/to/output3.txt
```

Alternative way would be to use `lsof -p $pid`, but I find it a bit on the heavy side than what you want to achieve, but the output would be same.

```
for pid in $(pgrep julia); 
do 
   lsof -p $pid | awk -v var=$pid '/1w/ {print var": "$9}'; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the PIDs of such processes, you can use `fuser`

```
$ fuser /path/to/outputfile
```

or `lsof`

```
$ lsof | grep "outputfile"
```

In order to avoid such a situation in future, use GNU Screen on the server (https://linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/using-gnu-screen-to-manage-persistent-terminal-sessions/).

Comment: Thank you. I'm using screen right now and It seems It is a perfect solution to Prevent such events. Thank you for your help.